# Handling Topology in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, topology

Can ArcGIS Online act as a solution for handling topology?

For example, if I have a hosted feature service with topology in it, can I maintain the topology in the hosted feature service using tools in Pro?

I am not sure how far AGOL has come and if it can now handle this. I know it could not in the past..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AGO relies on the same technology as ArcGIS DataStore for online Feature Services; so you don't have access to the full functionality of a Spatial Data Store like MSSQL Spatial or Oracle Spatial.